# Where is the location OWASP ZAP stored it's session (on Windows)

Tags: zap

As title, where is the location OWASP ZAP stored it's session (On Windows).

I have selected persistent session, so I expect to be able to retrieve the session back.

However, when I click `File -> Open Session`, it bring me to a location where no session is shown. Therefore I would like to know, where the session is being stored by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is stored here `"%HOMEPATH%\OWASP ZAP\sessions"` by default on Windows,

Note that it is `sessions` but not `session` (need the `s`)

*Note: it is ok to ask and answer your own question, see this https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions*